# Extending WCF Objects to add DataAnnotations.Key

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, entity-framework-6

After adding a Service Reference to a 3rd party WCF service (that I cannot change), and an EF6 Model with this code:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Model1
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=Model1")
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Property MyActivities() As DbSet(Of SomeWebService.Activity)
End Class
```

...I will call a method that will return an array of Activity objects which have properties of their own or through inheritance, as well as properties of other types defined by the WCF.  I want to dump the whole mess into a SQL database with this:

```
Dim DB As New Model1()
Dim SvcClient As SomeWebService.ServiceClient

For Each Activity As SomeWebService.Activity In SvcClient.GetObjects(foo)
    DB.MyActivities.Add(Activity)
Next

With DB
    .SaveChanges()
    .Dispose()
End With
```

This works, but only after modifying the generated WCF code to add `DataAnnotations.Key` to the appropriate properties so EF6 can identify the primary keys to properly create a database.

When the service reference is updated, all those changes are lost, so I need to have a separate file with the same namespace and partial classes and matching properties to apply the decorations:

```
Namespace SomeWebService

    Partial Public Class SomeObject
        <DataAnnotations.Key>
        Public Property Key() As Integer
    End Class

End Namespace
```

This produces the expected error:

```
Error   BC30269 'Public Property Key As Integer' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.
```

There are a bunch of properties that need this, not just one...how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why not using Fluent API instead of Data Annotations?

Comment: It's not a good idea using the service model this way, since the object can be modified by the provider. You should create your own model, even equals to the service model, but you can implement all that you need to persist, export, etc. Then you can map the service model to your model, avoiding this kind of problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev because that's where EF6 sent me when it couldn't determine a primary key field. Turns out marking those fields eliminated them from the stored data anyway, so I ended up doing partial classes and adding new properties with the .Key and with XmlIgnore to get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating new properties that would not collide with those in the WCF, decorating them with `DataAnnotations.Key` to create my own primary key columns in the database and with `XmlIgnore` to keep them out of the serializer:

```
Namespace SomeWebService

    Partial Public Class SomeObject
        <XmlIgnore, DataAnnotations.Key>
        Public Property UniqueID() As Integer
    End Class

End Namespace
```

It should be noted that @IvanStoev's suggestion of Fluent API is a good one, and may be a better idea depending on how one needs to deal with WCF data.